# Twig block USE in IF block

Tags: symfony, twig

I render same page in modal and self.

I wonder if there is some way to check for some condition and if condition is true not to include header and footer with use tag.

```
{% extends 'ProfileBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="..."/>
{% endblock %}

{% if modal is not defined %}
    {% use 'ProfileBundle::navigation.html.twig' %}
    {% use 'ProfileBundle::footer.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}

{% block main %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `use` tag in `twig`, you still need to call them if you want to render the blocks. So before rendering the blocks you can add your condition ([twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/dm9xff))

<kbd>page.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="text/css" href="page.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if not modal is defined %}{{ block('navigation') }}{% endif %}

    <h1>Content</h1>

    {% if not modal is defined %}{{ block('footer') }}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

<kbd>base.twig</kbd>

```
{% use "navigation.twig" %}
{% use "footer.twig" %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>      
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>navigation.twig</kbd>

```
{% block navigation %}
<nav id="main">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>footer.twig</kbd>

```
{% block footer %}
<footer>
    &copy; {{ "now" | date('Y') }}
</footer>
{% endblock %}
```